# collapse columns with logical value into one

Tags: r, dataframe

Mock data

```
df <- data.frame(posterior=rnorm(5), A=sample(c(T,F), 5, replace=T), 
             B=sample(c(T,F), 5, replace=T), C=sample(c(T,F), 5, replace=T) )
```

From this I hope to produce a data frame with 2 columns: the first is the same, the second is the names of all the variables (A, B, or C) that has TRUE. (This is done in context of variable selection.)

My current solution uses apply on each logical row, then extract the list of variable names by `colnames(df[2:4])[row]`. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates the column you're looking for, I believe:

```
df$Letters = apply(df[,2:4], 1, function(x) paste(names(x)[x], collapse=", "))
```

And you can isolate that to two columns with `df[,c("posterior", "Letters")]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorised solution if speed is important, but it is not particularly intuitive:

```
combs <- c("","A","B","AB","C","AC","BC","ABC") #all letter combinations in a binary order
transform(df, vars = combs[rowSums(t(t(df[2:4])*2^(0:2)))+1])
    posterior     A     B     C vars
1  1.28037818  TRUE  TRUE FALSE   AB
2 -0.07794835 FALSE  TRUE FALSE    B
3  0.86463032 FALSE FALSE  TRUE    C
4 -1.04609087 FALSE  TRUE FALSE    B
5 -1.13092499  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  ABC
```

Essentially you treat the rows as a representation of a binary number with digits representing the presence or absence of the variable. Then you just map this number to a vector of combinations.

**Edit**

To produce combs automatically you can use `intToBits` and `which`:

```
getCombs <- function(vars) c("", sapply(seq(2^length(vars)-1),
             function(x) paste(vars[which(intToBits(x)==1)],collapse="")))

getCombs(LETTERS[1:3])
[1] ""    "A"   "B"   "AB"  "C"   "AC"  "BC"  "ABC"
```

This takes under a second (on my machine) for up to 16 variables, an approximately doubles in time for each additional variable. This is because you double the number of combinations as you add another variable.

Comment: How would you extend this answer? Is there an easy way to create the "combs" in the correct order required here?

Comment: I still can't see an easy way to come up with the "combs" vector. I found a solution with `expand.grid`, but it is far too slow....

Comment: @AnandaMahto I've added a way of doing it, but it is still O(2^n) in the number of variables so not sure if it is faster than your `expand.grid` solution.

Comment: OK. Well thanks for taking the time to try! You'll get a bit of a performance boost in this case if you use `vapply` instead of `sapply`. I guess your solution is most applicable for a combination of a small number of columns but a large number of rows. I haven't been able to get anything more efficient than the `apply` approach in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I've been spending too much time thinking about this question (because I have a similar thing I'm working on on my own).

I really like James's answer... but as he mentioned, as the number of columns starts to increase, it will definitely slow down quite a bit. I also like Senor O's direct `apply` answer, and it's an answer that is really tough to beat.

Here's what I came up with.

```
logiNames <- function(inmatrix) {
  if (!is.matrix(inmatrix)) inmatrix <- as.matrix(inmatrix)
  if (is.null(colnames(inmatrix))) {
    stop("The whole point of this is to work with colnames")
  }
  dims <- dim(inmatrix)
  cn <- colnames(inmatrix)
  if (!is.logical(inmatrix)) inmatrix <- as.logical(inmatrix)
  M <- character(length(inmatrix))
  M[inmatrix] <- rep(cn, each = dims[1])[inmatrix]
  dim(M) <- dims
  do.call(paste0, data.frame(M))
}
```

Here are a couple of examples...

Sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
ncol = 10
nrow = 10
m <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol * nrow, TRUE), ncol = ncol, 
            dimnames=list(NULL, sample(c(letters, LETTERS), ncol, FALSE)))
n <- matrix(sample(c(1, 0), ncol * nrow, TRUE), ncol = ncol,
            dimnames=list(NULL, sample(c(letters, LETTERS), ncol, FALSE)))
```

On a `logical` matrix:

```
m
#           F     q     y     U     x     P     Q     B     s     g
#  [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#  [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#  [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#  [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#  [6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#  [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#  [8,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#  [9,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# [10,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

logiNames(m)
#  [1] "FxPsg"    "qxPQ"     "FxQsg"    "xPQB"     "qUxBsg"   "FUxPQBsg" "qxPB"
#  [8] "qUxg"     "qyUxBg"   "FyUPQBs"
```

On a matrix of zeroes and ones:

```
n
#       z m k H c G q s K N
#  [1,] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
#  [2,] 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
#  [3,] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#  [4,] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
#  [5,] 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
#  [6,] 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
#  [7,] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
#  [8,] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
#  [9,] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
# [10,] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
logiNames(n)
#  [1] "HKN"     "zmHcGqsK" "zmHc"    "mHcGs"   "mcGN"    "zHcsK"   "mHqsKN"
#  [8] "mHcGN"   "mHcGKN"   "zkcGN"
```

---

The benefits of this would really only be noticeable when you are dealing with data with a lot of ***rows***. For example, changing "ncol" to 20 and "nrow" to 1e5 in the data creation step above gives me these timings:

```
set.seed(123)
ncol = 20
nrow = 1e5
m <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), ncol * nrow, TRUE), ncol = ncol, 
            dimnames=list(NULL, sample(c(letters, LETTERS), ncol, FALSE)))

fun3 <- function() apply(m, 1, function(x) paste(colnames(m)[x], collapse=""))

system.time(fun3())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.427   0.000   2.441 
system.time(logiNames(m))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.860   0.001   0.868
```